# how to make the span elements on the image relative to the image resizing?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, css

I have an application where I am locating all the employees on the office layout. I have an Office layout image and the Json for each employee would have an x and y co-ordinate to indicate the location of the employee on the layout. The image is placed in a panel and when I resize the window the image also resizes accordingly. But the location of the employees do not resize. Following is my code:

```
<div class='col-lg-7 col-md-6 col-sm-12'>
            <div class='row'>
                <div class='col-xs-12'>
                    <div class='panel panel-default'>
                        <div class='panel-body'>
                            <div id="empMap">
                                <img  rel="prefetch" alt="Image is not found" ng-src="{{officeImage}}" id="empMap" style="width: 100%;height: 100%; z-index: -1" onerror="this.src='/img/OfficeImageNotAvailable.png'">
                                <div>
                                    <div ng-repeat="emp in employees">
                                        <span  class="glyphicon glyphicon-oil" id="{{emp.empId}}" ng-click="empDisplay($event)" ng-dblclick="empInfo($event)"
                                              ng-style="{'cursor': 'pointer','color':'green','position': 'absolute',
                                              'left': xValue + emp.location.xcoordinate, 'top': yValue - emp.location.ycoordinate, 'z-index': '2'}"/>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

Code in the controller:

```
$("#empMap").load(function() {//loading the image of the plant
            img_width = this.width;
            img_height = this.height;
            console.log("getting the values of the images");
            var img_left = $("#empMap").position().left;
            var img_top = $("#empMap").position().top;
            var y = img_height + img_top;
            $scope.xValue = img_left;
            $scope.yValue = y -14;
});
```

What I am doing in the above code is that I am calculating the xValue and yValue from top,left height and width values of the image and in my html I am adding the x and y co-ordinate values to this values.

I am not sure how I can move the location accordingly when the image is resized based. Also the location of the employee is not displayed properly. So could you let me know what I am missing here and what would be the better approach in this scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is only run when the page is initially loaded, to recalculate the positions when the browser window is resized you need to call the function again.

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
  Actions Go Here
});
```

Your best bet would probably be to establish your position calculation as a function on its own then call it from both .load and .resize so that your code is DRY.

Comment: Yes I understand that I have to call the resize function again. But the span elements are placed based on the x and y co-ordinate values returned from the web service and you can see it in the html. These x and y values are calculated for image with width 860px and height 540 px. But my image on the screen is 1056px and 550px so how I can transform these values based on the image size.